# How to generate a random number but not integer and not like 1.2321312312

Tags: javascript

I want to generate random number but not integer and not like 2.213124125 i want like that: 2.45 2.69 4.52

max 2 number after dot.

Also it returns the old value when i try to click another button.

```
  var buton = document.createElement("button");
  buton.innerHTML = "Tıkla";
buton.onclick = function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("has-input")[1];
    x.value = Math.random(Math.random() * 100) + 2;
}

  document.getElementsByClassName("place_bet m_t_30 bbb manual_bet_select")[0].appendChild(buton);
```

It generates 2.213123123123 but i want 2.21

And when i click to **"btn btn_green"** button (in site) it returns to the old value.

Comment: `Math.random(Math.random() * 100)` – you probably meant `Math.floor` at the start? (That’s not the end of it but a decent direction to explore.)

Comment: i know Math.floor but it generates integer and i dont want integer

Answer (score 3):

The [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method of numbers can return a string with the desired number of decimal places.

```
(Math.random() + 2).toFixed(2)
"2.96"
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but it returns to the old value when i click the **"btn btn_green"** which is in site that i cant change anything

Comment: Note that this can generate `"3.00"` because `toFixed` rounds. May or may not be expected.

Comment: True, though the question was never really clear about the desired range.

Comment: @CanBeyNABDINIZ It's one question at a time I'm afraid so you'll have to ask that as a new question (and I'd recommend giving some more detail when you do as there's not enough to possibly know what your green button might be doing)

Comment: If transforming the result of toFired() (returns a string) to a number again, the number becomes mostly inaccurate. Example: `parseFloat((1.456).toFixed(2)).toPrecision(18)`  is `1.45999999999999996`.

Comment: Yes, that is worth noting. In this case as it's being applied to a form field value, it doesn't need converting to a number so it's okay.

Comment: Another note: Because of rounding, the result is in the range 2.00 to 3.00 inclusive. The probabilities of the concrete values 2.00 and 3.00 is 1/200. For all other values it is 1/100.

Comment: Think you could do something like subtract 0.005 before rounding to make the range exclusive of 3.00 and every possible value have the same likelihood.

Answer (score -2):

```js
//This is using without string conversion
let num1 =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)/100)
console.log(num1)
//This is using 'toFixed()'
let num2 = (Math.random() + (Math.random() * 10)).toFixed(2)
console.log(num2)
```

Comment: It works too Thanks! But  it returns to the old value when i click the **"btn btn_green" **which is in site that i cant change anything

Comment: Combining 2 random() in is a bad decision because of the random quality of the result (to xompley to explain here). Second, your construct `Math.random() + Math.random() * 10)`expands the range from (0..11.0( and 5.5 has the highest probability. Compare the sum of 2 die of 1..6: range 2..12, mid numbers have higher probability than the numbers 1 or 12.

Comment: @Wiimm buddy i missed `()`. And i am not creating to random numbers for a single place value. One number(0-10) is for integer part and other is for decimal part